# Create async thunk loosing context if returned from another functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, this, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I want to create createAsyncThunk function wrapper, because want to refactor 3 big thunks in one with parameters. Here my solution.

Code

```
export const getExportThunk = <T>(
  handler: (args: T) => Promise<boolean>,
  route: string,
  successText: string
) =>
  createAsyncThunk<boolean, T>(
    route,
    async (args, {rejectWithValue, dispatch}) => {
      try {
        const res = await handler(args);
        return true;
      } catch (e: unknown) {
        return rejectWithValue('unknown');
      }
    }
  );
```

Usage.

```
export const exportWorkload = getExportThunk<IServerGetWorkloadBody>(
  api.exportWorkload,
  'ytd/exportWorkload',
  'YTD Workload was successfully downloaded!'
);
```

But when I'm trying to dispatch the result of getExportThunk, I catch an error that says: this is undefined. How to pass context in this case and moreover which context it should be?

Error stacktrace:
[stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StPiQ.png)

Place where redux promise function fails

```
const promise = (async function () {
        let finalAction: ReturnType<typeof fulfilled | typeof rejected>
        try {
          let conditionResult = options?.condition?.(arg, { getState, extra })
          if (isThenable(conditionResult)) {
            conditionResult = await conditionResult
          }
          if (conditionResult === false) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
            throw {
              name: 'ConditionError',
              message: 'Aborted due to condition callback returning false.',
            }
          }
          started = true
          dispatch(
            pending(
              requestId,
              arg,
              options?.getPendingMeta?.({ requestId, arg }, { getState, extra })
            )
          )
//fails in this asignment
          finalAction = await Promise.race([
            abortedPromise,
            Promise.resolve(
              payloadCreator(arg, {
                dispatch,
                getState,
                extra,
                requestId,
                signal: abortController.signal,
                rejectWithValue: ((
                  value: RejectedValue,
                  meta?: RejectedMeta
                ) => {
                  return new RejectWithValue(value, meta)
                }) as any,
                fulfillWithValue: ((value: unknown, meta?: FulfilledMeta) => {
                  return new FulfillWithMeta(value, meta)
                }) as any,
              })
            ).then((result) => {
              if (result instanceof RejectWithValue) {
                throw result
              }
              if (result instanceof FulfillWithMeta) {
                return fulfilled(result.payload, requestId, arg, result.meta)
              }
              return fulfilled(result as any, requestId, arg)
            }),
          ])
        } catch (err) {
          finalAction =
            err instanceof RejectWithValue
              ? rejected(null, requestId, arg, err.payload, err.meta)
              : rejected(err as any, requestId, arg)
        }
```

Comment: Don't upload images of code. Paste the code in the question so that we can modify it.

Comment: I'm very confused - `createAsyncThunk` definitely doesn't use the `this` keyword at all, and I don't see `this` in your own code anywhere. It must be coming from inside your own code, in `api.exportWorkload`.  Can you show that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @markerikson said, the problem was with context of api.exportWorkload, it was loosing its context after firing it as handler() and was trying to get access to it. The solution.

```
export const exportWorkload = getExportThunk<IServerGetWorkloadBody>(
  api.exportWorkload.bind(api),
  'ytd/exportWorkload',
  'YTD Workload was successfully downloaded!'
);
```

Or use arrow function instead default function

```
  public exportWorkload = async (body: IServerGetWorkloadBody) => {
    const res = await this.ytdService.exportWorkload(body);

    return res;
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Please mark this answer as solution of your initial question.